# How comments work in the context of a regexp switch statement

Tags: regex, tcl

Ok, So I can't seem to figure out how on earth this works. The Attached code when ran results in an invalid command name "      " while executing "\t" ("#" arm line 1) invoked from within "switch -regexp -- $line { "(and the rest of the file basically)

I ran into this problem and finally figured out the # was doing it, I tried escaping it using regsub (shown below). The only way I can get the string to parse is if I remove the # all together from the string (inputString changed to remove the # sign).

Based on the statement that TCL reads all lines as text (including commands) I could only assume that the string being read contained a # and couldn't complete the line and of course returned an error. However escaping (tried 1 \ and 2 \'s) didn't do anything to make it better All it did was add \ to all my other "non word chars" (I had -'s that worked fine, but now have \'s...:S)

If I Delete OR Uncomment out the switch section {^[ \t]*TEST.*$} the thing works fine.

I am modifying a script and was ignoring a particular couple cases, and decided to comment them out.

Can someone explain what on earth is happening, and what I can do to fix it? It appears that the .tcl file is still parsing the # sections even though they're comments, and getting confused.

Attempt to fix

```
regsub -all {\W} $line {\\&} line;
```

Code:

```
    proc doConversion fname {
    set inputString "* |# Bits\n*  # Bits \n";

    foreach line [split $inputString "\n"] { 
       switch -regexp  -- $line {
                # {^[ \t]*TEST.*$}
                # {
                   # # Do nothing
                # }
               default {

                       }
            }
       }

    }

doConversion "test"
```

Update:
I did find this resource, which explains (to an extent) the confusing nature of comments but I guess I'm still not sure what I can do about it: ["Why can I not place unmatched braces in Tcl comments"](http://wiki.tcl.tk/462).

Comment: The nature of Tcl's comment mechanism is such that `#` is a comment only at the point where the start of a command is being expected. Plus embedded scripts (such as the arms of a `switch`) can cause alteration of where the end of a comment is. This _is_ different to other languages, and is a consequence of the general syntax rules and the way Tcl does recursive decomposition of commands. Every few years, someone proposes to “fix” it, but it's much harder to change than it appears to be at first glance…

Comment: Yea reading through the TCL wiki linked above....it's a bit confusing.....that's for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, so I apologize in advance if this doesn't answer your question, but: the upshot is, `#` doesn't indicate a comment unless it's somewhere that a command is expected. For example, this:

```
switch -regexp a#b {
    # {
        echo 'a#b' contains '#'
    }
}
```

prints this:

```
'a#b' contains '#'
```

because the string `a#b` successfully matches the regex `#`.

Since `$line` contains `#`, your code:

```
       switch -regexp  -- $line {
                # {^[ \t]*TEST.*$}
                ...
            }
```

will run this command:

```
^[ \t]*TEST.*$
```

which (because of the square brackets) runs this command:

```
\t
```

so you get an error message telling you that `"   "` (i.e., the tab character) is an invalid command name.

If you want to disable one branch of a `switch`, you're better off wrapping it in a condition that will never be satisfied:

```
    proc doConversion fname {
    set inputString "* |# Bits\n*  # Bits \n";

    foreach line [split $inputString "\n"] { 
       switch -regexp  -- $line {
               this-regexp-will-never-match {
                  {^[ \t]*TEST.*$}
                  {
                   # # Do nothing
                  }
               }
               default {

                       }
            }
       }

    }

doConversion "test"
```

Comment: Still very odd (I'm not very familiar with the language), however removing the # from the string (by a regsub of # for pound) seems to remove the problem.

Comment: Also, I did try to remove the commented out sections, just to see if it would work (in my bigger program) and still wouldn't so I had to resort to the #/pound swap.

Comment: @onaclov2000: Yup, because then the string doesn't match the regex `#`, so `switch` never tries to run the problematic command.

Comment: @onaclov2000: I tested what I posted. If removing the commented-out sections didn't solve your problem, then that means you have another problem as well.

Comment: I really just can't post the larger part of the program so at this point I'm not sure what the "secondary" issue was specifically, but it was still comment related. If I get a chance "abstract it out" and post an example I'll do that for sure!